# RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" is nil

Tags: xcode, react-native, metro-bundler, xcode-scheme

I have a debug and release configuration. I've duplicated debug scheme and configuration, and set the new (duplicate of debug) scheme to the duplicate of debug configuration. I've had to manually set `DEBUG=1` to the new configuration too (for some reason it doesn't get copied).

Now in the new configuration when I hit the `return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];` line it returns `nil` and crashes with the following error:

```
No bundle URL present.

Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.
```

Metro is running. If I switch to the default Debug scheme, it works normally and `[[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"]` returns `http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=my.bundle.id.redacted` which is correct and working.

Why isn't my duplicated scheme/config (that only has bundle ID overridden), which is a direct duplicate of my working Debug scheme/config returning `nil` for the JS bundle path?

Comment: Having the same issue when I'm trying to upgrade from RN 0.68.7 to 0.72...did you ever figure it out?